# how to translate the texts with python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to translate some texts with else if but I can't find the way to do it:
What I try to translate is the following part of the code:

```
rarity = {api["rarity"]}
        if rarity:
            rarity="epico"
        else:
            rarity="epic"



            if rarity:
                rarity="un poco comun"
            else:
                rarity="uncommon"   



        
        print(f'Rareza: {rarity}')
```

But I can't figure out how to do it

This is the complete code that I am using:

```
import json
import requests

args= input("Escribe: ")

response = requests.get("https://jose89fcb.es/apifortnite/fish.php")
data = response.json()


match_found = False
for api in data['fish']:
    
    if args == api["name"]: 
        print(f'Imagen: {api["image"]}')
        print(f'Descripción: {api["description"]}')



        rarity = {api["rarity"]}
        if rarity:
            rarity="epico"
        else:
            rarity="epic"



            if rarity:
                rarity="un poco comun"
            else:
                rarity="uncommon"   



        
        print(f'Rareza: {rarity}')


        match_found = True
if not match_found:
    print("Error")
```

Could someone give me a hand? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Into which language are you trying to translate this?

Comment: to the Spanish language

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are trying to do. As far as I can tell, the strings are already in Spanish. Even if not, how is that a programming problem? Are you trying to *program* something that does the translation automatically?

Comment: So, you get a "rarity" in English and would like to instead get that in the Spanish equivalent. Is that correct?

Comment: I am trying to change the string "rarity", and change it to the language to Spanish, currently in the api it appears in English

Comment: FWIW, notwithstanding the language this code is nonsense. `rarity` will always be truthy both times it is checked, since it is explicitly set to a non-empty container right beforehand.

Comment: Just to be clear: You mean `api["rarity"]` can be the string `"epic"` or `"uncommon"` and in these cases `rarity` should be set to `"epico"` or `"un poco comun"`, respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you understand what `if rarity` means. That just means, check if its value is considered `True` or `False`. If a string has any content in it, this will be considered `True`. Perhaps you meant to check if its content was equal to the English version, and you want to translate it to the Spanish version?

You could do this via `if-elif`:

```
rarity = {api["rarity"]}
if rarity == "epic":
    rarity = "epico"
elif rarity == "uncommon":
    rarity = "un poco comun"

print(f'Rareza: {rarity}')
```

Or a `dict`:

```
translations = {
    "epic": "epico",
    "uncommon": "un poco comun"
}

rarity = translations[rarity]
print(f'Rareza: {rarity}')
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary that takes English keys and returns Spanish values is what you are likely after:

```py
rarity_en_to_sp = {
    "epic": "epico",
    "uncommon": "un poco comun",
}

rarity_en = "uncommon"
rarity_sp = rarity_en_to_sp.get(rarity_en, rarity_en)
print(f'Rarity: {rarity_en} Rareza: { rarity_sp }')

rarity_en = "unknown"
rarity_sp = rarity_en_to_sp.get(rarity_en, rarity_en)
print(f'Rarity: {rarity_en} Rareza: { rarity_sp }')
```

The use of `get()` here allows us to fall back to whatever the English version was in the event we don't have a translation yet.

This code should give you:

```
Rarity: uncommon Rareza: un poco comun
Rarity: unknown Rareza: unknown
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Google Translate library if it's for a small-sized project.

Use pip to install `googletrans` library:

```
pip3 install googletrans
```

And then for example:

```
# import library
from googletrans import Translator, constants

# initialize translator instance
translator = Translator()

# translate something to English from Italian (English is the default)
translation = translator.translate("Ciao Mondo!")
print(f"{translation.origin} ({translation.src}) --> {translation.text} ({translation.dest})")
```

---

Output:
`Ciao Mondo! (it) --> Hello World! (en)`

Source: [How to Translate Languages in Python](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/translate-text-in-python)

If you get an error similar to this: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` (which I got too), use these commands to install the specific version of the library that is used in the code above:

```
pip3 uninstall googletrans
pip3 install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```